# Open Source Dialog System Natural Language Processing Engine?

Tags: open-source, nlp, language, ruby, artificial-intelligence

## Introduction and goal

I'm interested to develop (possibly in Ruby language) ***Conversational Commerce Chat Apps*** [1].

## A Dialog System Engine ?

Specifically I want to implement a *dialog system engine*, a natural language server middleware to be used by business applications to achive specific *deterministic* business actions (online shopping: submit orders, booking: submit a reservation, supply any service) from bots running inside chat instant messaging platforms as http://www.Telegram.org (through Bot APIs, see my project [2][7]) or team-working chat as http://www.slack.com, or whatever IM system supply bot APis (maybe soon: Messenger/Whatsapp, Google Chat, etc. etc. ).

## API.ai / WIT.ai approach

I'm studying now these two similar dialog system cloud / proprietary engines: http://api.ai and http://wit.ai (see interesting introductive articles by Patrick Cantazariti: [4][5][6] and my notes about excellent API.ai: [9][10]).

These platforms have a pretty similar approach (that someone call *euristic/pragmatic systems*, or *dialog scripts systems*), where **a conversational application (called *agent* in api.ai terminology, or *app* in wit.ai case) is modeled as a set of *intents* acting on *entities* in certain *domains*, letting you to collect *actionable data*** and so implementing a conversation that collect data to *action* what I call a *deterministic goal* (e.g. submitting an ecommerce order, reserve a room on a hotel, etc. etc.).

I feel that above approach to model a conversation (dialog modeled as *domains*/*entities*/*intents*/*contexts*/*actionable data*) is a good compromise between:

- a vast/complex "Artificial Intelligence" dialog engine that have to understand "any" natural language user sentence (e.g. the fact-totum user "assistant" approach a la Facebook "M", Apple Siri", etc.),
- and an hard-coded approach, as I done with my modest experimental project "dialogs" [3], where I modeled a conversation as a composition of dialogs, where each dialog is a sort of finite state machine.

### Some notes/issues

1. **Data privacy**

   API.ai and WIT.ai have a great web interface to build-up easyly dialogs but i see a big problem: to model by example an ecommerce workflow, there is a need to define *users entities* where the personal data of the application and the users have to be "ingestioned"/stored on the proprietary cloud system (e.g. API.ai); that's a data privacy problem; in my opinion is bad that final business application and personal user data are maintained on a single (proprietary) cloud system.
2. **Software Opening**

   - A possible desiderata is to have a open-source software, to be instanstiated on private servers to maintains data private. All in all that "Dialog System" platform have to be as a database (DBMS): let's consider Postgresql/REDIS as great example of open software service platform paradigma: each developer install his own database server instance where store his private data.
   - Having something like API.ai as open-software could help also to SHARE dialog agent *interchange format dialog scripts*, maybe achieving a common standard (text files easy to download/upload).

## The Main Question

1. **There is something similar to API.ai but open-source ?** If not:
2. **There is any interest to build up now a community to create similar project ?**

Any suggestion/comment/answer welcome.

giorgio

## Links:

[1] [my microblog](http://www.twitter.com/solyarisoftware)
[2] [BOTServer on github](http://www.github.com/solyaris/BOTServer)
[3] [((dialogs)) on github](http://www.github.com/solyaris/dialogs)
[4] [Five Simple Ways to Build Artificial Intelligence in 2016](http://www.sitepoint.com/five-simple-ways-to-build-artificial-intelligence-in-2016/)
[5] [How to Build Your Own AI Assistant Using Api.ai](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-your-own-ai-assistant-using-api-ai/)
[6] [Customizing Your Api.ai Assistant with Intent and Context](http://www.sitepoint.com/customizing-your-api-ai-assistant-with-intent-and-context/)
[7] [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api)
[8] [Welcome to Slack API](https://api.slack.com/)
[9] [What are contexts and how are they used?](https://api.ai/blog/2015/11/23/Contexts/#comment-2489378524)
[10] [API.ai vs Sirius ?](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-your-own-ai-assistant-using-api-ai/#comment-2482573014)

Comment: Welcome and congrats!  I believe that is the first time the word *desiderata* has been used in this SE.

Answer (score 2):

here are a couple resources I have found, that provide an open source "dialog system".

1. https://github.com/superscriptjs/superscript  (Javascript)
   I just ran this yesterday locally, with the telnet interface for rules it looks interesting.  There is an example using websockets; but I didn't get that working as of yet.
2. https://github.com/plison/opendial  (Java)
   I just discovered this and have not tried it.

I am also interested in this.  This area of develop "dialog systems" seems to be changing fast and getting a lot of resources.  I do think the more intuitive setup and configuration like wi.ai offers (I have not yet used api.ai) is a needed piece that is lacking in open source.  I'd like to work on something (assuming we all can find the time); I'd like to see maybe something built with NodeRed for an interface to then be able build the "dialog system"--but that is just an initial idea.

I am still researching this area--so there may be more and better options also.

Best regards!

Comment: Hi @petegordon 
BTW, today api.ai become part pf Google! 
BTW, I suggest ChatScript open-source (I'm contributing on documentation rework) and I kindly invite to read my article about open-source/proprietary chatbots platforms debate: https://medium.com/@solyarisoftware/chatscript-for-beginners-chatbots-developers-c58bb591da8#.qyh2u5npb